# How to fix "operating system not found" after spilling water over the computer and using boot-repair?

Tags: 12.04, boot-repair

I have a Sony VAIO that originally had Windows 7 installed on it but I decided to format and install 12.04. After **spilling water on it**, I didn't turn it off right away and a minute later the screen went black so I turned off and on again and it said

> Operating System Not Found

I left it overnight disassembled to dry. I turn it on today and it works. About 2 minutes after boot, screen stops responding and I have to manually turn it off, gives me the same OS not found error.

So I booted the LiveCD I had for Ubuntu and connected to the Internet and installed then tried using the `boot-repair` application to fix it. Gave me the message no operating system found too.

How to access my data and OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your hard drive might have been damaged by some of the water. This could have messed with the main boot files in Ubuntu to the point where they are unrecognisable/recoverable.

Try booting up with the live CD, and see of you can access your documents etc. from your hard drive, and then back them all up (to a portable hard drive or flash drive) and do a fresh install. This will prevent any future corruption issues (hopefully) and allow you to boot into a fresh system with which you can restore your backed up data.

Probably not what you wanted to hear, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I wasn't able to locate my HDD or any of my files when booting from LiveCD, I tried a few methods, any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), which is a tool to recover documents on damaged disks.